# Twitter Streaming API response 429 ("too many requests"). How can I cash data?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, datacash, sttwitterapi

I'm trying to get all tweets depends on location. I use Twitter Streaming API `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/reverse_geocode.json`.

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool){
twitterService!.requestTweetsWithCoordinates(mapView.centerCoordinate)
    }
```

However, seems I do it too often and after few requests get an error 429.
I understand that I need to cash data, but I don't know the best way.
Maybe, I need to track some radius, and when I go out the bounds - perform new request to TwitterAPI.
Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!